# Lubuntu 14.04 show internal error after battery is drained

Tags: 14.04, boot, lubuntu, battery

I use a 2011 MacBook with Lubuntu 14.04 Whenever I have used up all the battery I get an Ubuntu Internal Error which disappears after rebooting again.. The error does not affect usability but is weird.

May I ask why does this happen? (Next time when it happens I will add more details to the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been going on for a long time now and is not something to be worried about, according to me.
Sometime we need to clear the apport to stop it from displaying an error report on every restart.
Open terminal

`cd /var/crash`

warning: next command deletes everything in the directory

`sudo rm -r *
 exit`

P.S.- be sure to be in the right directory before executing the `rm` command. What we are doing is removing the crash reports from you system - if there is an error still going on, a new crash report will be generated.

Comment: Thanks..I know that sudo rm -r * is very dangerous in any directory that is not the targeted one since it removes everything inside your current directory..Would you please add a warning?